# Error Starting Jetty-Service (Solr)

Tags: java, windows, solr, jetty

**Update:** I installed the 32bit JDK and the service starts fine now. No idea why though. The machine it was failing on was 64bit...

**Update2:** So installing the 32bit JDK will allow the service to install, but solr will not run. There is a StackOverflowException and NullPointer Excpetions in the logs.

I am trying to run Jetty as a service on Windows 7 64bit. I have it running on a very similar machine just fine, but on the second I am getting errors I have not been able to resolve.

The service installs fine, however when you try to start it you get the message in the console: The Jetty6-Service service was launched, but failed to start.

[image]

This is the related contents in the jetty-service.log:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | Starting the Jetty6-Service service...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | Using tick timer.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | server listening on port 32000.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | Launching a JVM...
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | command: "java" -Djetty.home=../ -Djetty.logs=../logs -Dsolr.solr.home=C:/solr/ -Xms5m -Xmx64m -Djava.library.path="../lib/win32/" -classpath "../lib/win32/jetty-win32-service-java-6.1.26.jar;../lib/win32/wrapper.jar;../lib/jetty-6.1.3.jar;../lib/jetty-util-6.1.3.jar;../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.3.jar;../start.jar" -Dwrapper.key="c5CIhIjsO0gmMcTE" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=4708 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.mortbay.jetty.win32service.JettyServiceWrapperListener ../etc/jetty.xml
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 |     "java" -Djetty.home=../ -Djetty.logs=../logs -Dsolr.solr.home=C:/solr/ -Xms5m -Xmx64m -Djava.library.path="../lib/win32/" -classpath "../lib/win32/jetty-win32-service-java-6.1.26.jar;../lib/win32/wrapper.jar;../lib/jetty-6.1.3.jar;../lib/jetty-util-6.1.3.jar;../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.3.jar;../start.jar" -Dwrapper.key="c5CIhIjsO0gmMcTE" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=4708 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.mortbay.jetty.win32service.JettyServiceWrapperListener ../etc/jetty.xml
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:07 | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2011/02/16 12:50:09 | The Jetty6-Service service was launched, but failed to start.
```

The one difference that I know of between the two machines is that the one that is not working had Tomcat installed at one point which it no longer does.

I have tried the following:

1. Uninstalled all copies of the Java JDK and JRE
2. Reinstalled the latest Java JDK - jdk1.6.0_24 which installs the associated JRE
3. Tried setting JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24
4. Googled all error messages
5. I can run java -version in the console without error

In case someone is looking for more information on running Jetty as a service, check out:

1. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Win32Wrapper
2. http://technologyenablingbusiness.blogspot.com/2010/12/solr-on-jetty-as-windows-service.html

Comment: can run run the command `java -version` from that console? as the java binary might not be in the path.

Comment: Yes, I can run java -version:

C:\solr>java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Is there any way to increase the logging level of the service? It looks like it's at ERROR+; perhaps DEBUG or INFO level logs would help.

Comment: @Rob I updated the log section in the question above to show logging with the level set at debug. Not much more info I am afraid.

Comment: "Unable to execute Java command." It seems simple,  but are you sure the script has the right PATH information to find the java executable? Can you edit the script to use an absolute path?

Comment: Winsw worked well for me to start java services.  Requires .NET though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be issues with the Java Service Wrapper included as part of the Jetty Service on some x64 machines.

The community version of the Java Service Wrapper does not support x64 though. If I download and incorporate the standard or professional edition using method 4 on their website then things will work.

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Added to top of `bin\jetty-service.conf:`

```
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe
```

Note that `JAVA_HOME` in my system is set:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_35
```

and I'm using a 64 bit JVM:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like your paths aren't setup properly.

You should be able to run this command alone from the command line (copied from above)

"java" -Djetty.home=../ -Djetty.logs=../logs -Dsolr.solr.home=C:/solr/ -Xms5m -Xmx64m -Djava.library.path="../lib/win32/" -classpath "../lib/win32/jetty-win32-service-java-6.1.26.jar;../lib/win32/wrapper.jar;../lib/jetty-6.1.3.jar;../lib/jetty-util-6.1.3.jar;../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.3.jar;../start.jar" -Dwrapper.key="c5CIhIjsO0gmMcTE" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=4708 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.mortbay.jetty.win32service.JettyServiceWrapperListener ../etc/jetty.xml

It should tell you what the problem is when you do that.  Just run it from the same directory /bin I assume.

Is the java version jar the same as the version you have in your comand (6.1.26)?

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with `service jetty start`

got error:

> Cannot find VM in Java Home

The solution was to change

```
/etc/default/jetty
```

to

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
```

Comment: I doubt, that Unix-specific paths and a Unix shell script help much in the Windows environment of the original question.